# What type represents typing.Any except None?

Tags: python, type-hinting

I would like to annotate a variable such as it can be of any value *except* `None`, something like:

```
x: typing.Required(typing.Any) = 42
```

The `typing` module has the `Union` function, but there is no counterpart that would allow to exclude.

Comment: `Any` disables typechecking, it does not validate each object, therefore `Any, except None` is not possible. You may want to try `object` instead, but IDK how to exclude NoneType from it, or if it is even possible. (Union conserves only the most encompassing types, so this route seems closed)

Comment: The documentation only mentions "Every type is compatible with Any / Any is compatible with every type". I'm not aware of implementation details or how they were adjusted with new versions of Python.